# Let $_{125}$ be the field of $125$ elements. The number of non-zero elements $ ∈ _{125}$ such that $^5 =\alpha$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> Let $_{125}$ be the field of $125$ elements. The number of non-zero elements $ ∈ _{125}$ such that $^5 =\alpha?$

I don't know how to approach in a correct way, but $\alpha^5=\alpha\implies \alpha^5-\alpha=0$. So we need to consider a sub-field containing $5$ elements such that every element is a root of above equation. Right? Since we need non-zero elements so the answer should be $4$. Is my reasoning correct? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You showed that there should be at most four non-zero elements $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_{125}$ such that $\alpha^5=\alpha$. Can you explain why there are four such elements?

Comment: No it is just my thought. As $0$ obviously satisfies the equation, so over a field of $5$ elements, the non-zero elements remains 4

Comment: Have you seen the fact that a field of 125 elements necessarily has a subfield of 5 elements?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen i also  come across this question ,Can you please check my solution ,Here group of order $124$ will be cyclic which is $4\times 31$ so every cyclic group has a group of order of its divisor so it also have a group of order $4$ which is cyclic ,so there are 4 elements such that $x^4=e$

Answer (score 3):

A typical construction of $\mathbb{F}_{125}$ is as the splitting field of $p(x) = x^{125} - x$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$. Since $x^5 - x$ is a factor of $p(x)$, it follows that $\mathbb{F}_{125}$ contains all the roots of $x^5 - x$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$. We know there are 5 of these, namely the elements of $\mathbb{F}_5$ themselves, so your conclusion is correct.

Comment: Why are these the only solution of $p(x)$?

Comment: $p$ has degree 125, and so it cannot have more roots.

Comment: But these are just 5 roots, right?